# Singleton pattern in PHP 8.0 and private magic methods

Tags: php, singleton, warnings

I am using a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class in PHP according to the following pattern:

```
class MY_Singleton
{
    public static function instance()
    {
      static $instance = false;
      if( $instance === false )
      {
        // Late static binding (PHP 5.3+)
        $instance = new static();
      }

      return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Make constructor private, so nobody can call "new Class".
     */
    private function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Make clone magic method private, so nobody can clone instance.
     */
    private function __clone() {}

    /**
     * Make sleep magic method private, so nobody can serialize instance.
     */
    private function __sleep() {}

    /**
     * Make wakeup magic method private, so nobody can unserialize instance.
     */
    private function __wakeup() {}

}
```

This used to work just fine under PHP 7.X.X. Now, under PHP 8.0 I am getting warnings such as:

```
Warning: The magic method My_Singleton::__wakeup() must have public visibility in [...]
```

Should I implement a singleton differently under PHP 8.0? Or should I just turn off these warnings? If so, how do I do this in a way that is backward compatible with PHP 7.X.X?

Comment: It really makes no sense to have the magic methods as Private surely

Comment: If you really want to disallow those, it's probably best to just throw exceptions inside the function bodies.

Comment: It does. For a singleton or any class that is written under the assumption that users cannot instantiate clone it. Please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: `__wakeup`, if defined, is controlled by the class. If you implement it you can just do nothing, and nothing will then happen. I’m a fan of factory classes in certain scenarios, but at a certain point I just don’t fight people doing things I don’t support. There’s reflection and JSON to think about, too.

Answer (score 3):

A quote from the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php):

> WARNING All magic methods, with the exception of __construct(), __destruct(), and __clone(), must be declared as public, otherwise an E_WARNING is emitted. Prior to PHP 8.0.0, no diagnostic was emitted for the magic methods __sleep(), __wakeup(), __serialize(), __unserialize(), and __set_state().

Change these magic methods to public or remove them entirely if you do not use them. The only reason `__construct` makes sense as a private method is to prevent the possibility of multiple instances of your class, I guess the same could be said for `__destruct`, and `__clone`. For the other methods it simply makes no sense, and PHP 8 has finally implemented a warning.